# Resend an email from SFMC using SF-CRM- IER data

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a usecase - If an individual requests the company to resend an email(originally sent from SFMC) to them or forward it to another person. How do you achieve this in SFMC? I have BatchID, JobID, MergeID, Email ID available on IER(Individual Email Results) in SFCRM.Any thoughts Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can resend the email just based on the Individual Email Result record you have.

The biggest problem with this is that the IER record doesn't provide data source attributes for the send nor a way to link it to the data source.

Even if you insist that the email only needs the subscriber key value, I would imagine you still had to do tons of work. E.g. How do you design for the single send? How to get send classification Id, sender profile ID, etc..

Comment: Thanks Duc for your comment.. Agree totally

Answer (score -1):

We have built a custom app that will allow the Salesforce user to (1) preview a send-time personalized email in the IER object and (2) resend the individual email with send time personalization to the contact/lead.  In addition the email will come from the Salesforce user.  For a walk through of this functionality please see here: https://handsonsfmc.com/preview-resend-app-overview/

We are looking for beta testers of our app.  If you are a good candidate we'll send you the code to config in CRM and SFMC for free.  If interested please sign up here: https://handsonsfmc.com/preview-resend-open-source-code/

Comment: Thanks TimZ for your comment. Will reach out to you on LinkedIn